# phpmyadmin refresh does not refresh sometimes

Tags: phpmyadmin

I make an update using sqlalchemy

```
#todo use update
conn = engine.connect()
metadata=MetaData()
user = Table('user', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
stmt = user.update().where(user.columns.id==user_id).\
            values(age=age, person_type=person, lifestage_grp=lifestage)
conn.execute(stmt)
```

Then I refresh my phpmyadmin hitting the little green refresh icon but it does not refresh.

But when click another table and then click back, it is refreshed and displays updated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're pressing the button that refreshes the navigation window only (the red arrow in my screenshot below). To refresh or reload the results page, you should use the "Refresh" text in the results area (the blue arrow below). It can be a little deceptive, but they both refresh different aspects of the page.

[image: phpMyAdmin results window]